# Man and woman bringing out unity in the service of Hashem

Tags: sources-mekorot, parshanut-torah-comment, commentaries

In the [*Artscroll Stone Chumash*](http://www.artscroll.com/Details.aspx?itemNo=9781422613870) it says on page 15 the following:

לבשר אחד - *One flesh.*

... The *Tur* says, *“Man and wife are in reality one flesh, as they were at the beginning of Creation."*

Where does the *Tur* say this?

Comment: See Rav Hirsch's commentary on the Chumash (*B'reishis* 2:24).

Answer (score 2):

See [Sefaria](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.2.24?lang=bi&with=Tur%20HaAroch&lang2=he) where the Tur HaAruch is quoted in full on Bereshis (2:24):

> ודבק באשתו והיו לבשר אחד. פי' ראוי לדבק באשתו שלא לזנות עם אחרת כי הוא
>   ואשתו הם בשר אחד כאשר היה בתחלת היצירה: